# How to create trend boxplot in longitudinal data per patient?

Tags: r, statistics, data-visualization, boxplot, longitudinal

I have a set of longitudinal data with ID, Time, and some variables:

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4) #ID

X2<c(Day1,Day1,Day2,Day3,Day1,Day1,NA,Day1,NA,Day3,Day3,Day1,NA,Day2,Day2,Day2)  #Time

X3<-c(1.2, 2.2, 4.6, 1.5, 4.4, 5.2, 3.4, 2.1, 3, 5, 1.1, 3.8, 2.2, 3.6, 1.1, 4.2 ) #Variable of interest

X4<- c( a,a,b,a,c,c,c,c,a,b,b,b,a,b,c,a) #Variable of interest


data<-data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4)
```

What I need to do is to create a box plot to show the trend but not the overall trend, the per-patient trend!

Meaning that instead of having 16 rows of longitudinal data, I need to have 1 row for each patient. I also should not aggregate the data.

Does anyone have any solution on how to do this? I am not very familiar with stat and r

Comment: Do you want a Boxplot of every x2 filled with x4 per x3?

Comment: @Quinten Thank you for your question Every X2 filled with X3, AND every X2 filled with X3 per X4

Comment: If this is a sample of your actual patient level data, boxplots are a bad idea because there are only 1 to 3 observations per combination of the X variables. The boxplot is a 5-number summary. It's not possible to make a meaningful 5-number summary of 1, 2, or 3 data points.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```r
X1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4) #ID
X2<-c('Day1','Day1','Day2','Day3','Day1','Day1',NA,'Day1',NA,'Day3','Day3','Day1',NA,'Day2','Day2','Day2')  #Time
X3<-c(1.2, 2.2, 4.6, 1.5, 4.4, 5.2, 3.4, 2.1, 3, 5, 1.1, 3.8, 2.2, 3.6, 1.1, 4.2 ) #Variable of interest
X4<- c( 'a','a','b','a','c','c','c','c','a','b','b','b','a','b','c',"a") #Variable of interest

data<-data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X2, y = X3)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If I understand you correctly, you can use the following code using `facet_wrap` like this:

```r
X1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4) #ID
X2<-c('Day1','Day1','Day2','Day3','Day1','Day1',NA,'Day1',NA,'Day3','Day3','Day1',NA,'Day2','Day2','Day2')  #Time
X3<-c(1.2, 2.2, 4.6, 1.5, 4.4, 5.2, 3.4, 2.1, 3, 5, 1.1, 3.8, 2.2, 3.6, 1.1, 4.2 ) #Variable of interest
X4<- c( 'a','a','b','a','c','c','c','c','a','b','b','b','a','b','c',"a") #Variable of interest

data<-data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(X1 = as.factor(X1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X3)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~X4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks Quintien but my question is, if I do this, won`t the box plots be based on the overall data? Or these are based on per-patient records? Because what I want is the per-patient box plots

Comment: Hi @Aura, check my updated answer! Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @Quinten but I believe this could not be true because right now IDs are 4, but in reality, I have 100 patients with the overall 400 observations (so the x axis would go to 100 in that case). What I mean is in my example, we have 16 rows right? So when you want to plot it, the x axis would be time and y axis would be the total 16 observations, but what I want is that the y axis be based on observations per patient meaning y axis should be based on 4, not 16 if that makes sense

Comment: for example patient number 1 has 3 observations for x3=1.2,2.2,4.6 so boxplot should be based on an overall look of these 3 (which is my issue because I dont know how I can somehow pool these 3 observations for the 3 time point that patient nimber 1 has)